# should I call functions of `Service` in UI thread?

Tags: android, service

If I have a local `Service` and in the the `Service`, I have the function: `doHeavyThings()`. After I connected my `Activity` with the local `Service` in `onServiceConnected(...)`, should I call `mService.doHeavyThings()` in UI thread? Does it block my UI thread? can anyone explain it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `Service` <strike>always</strike> by default** runs on the UI Thread.
So, in order to avoid ANR's your `doHeavyThings()` method should be just starting a new `Thread` which does all the heavy lifting.

If you want to be informed about the result you must implement it by yourself. You could for instance pass a `Messanger` to the `Service` which will be used to communicate from the `Service` back to the caller.

The following article explains how to use a `Messanger` in a `Service` to provide two-way communication:
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html

Another way is to use an `IntentService`. You can read more about it here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html

** - You can run it in a seperate process using the `android:process` attribute in your `<service>` declaration inside of the `AndroidManifest.xml` file. (Thanks Class Stacker)

Comment: Just a note. A Service can also run on the main ("UI") thread of a process which belongs to the app, but is separate from the process in which the main UI thread for the activities runs. Of course, this then asks for IPC. -- My understanding of the OP was that it's a third party service. Also, my understang was that the question only related to the invocation of such a third party service.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on whether or not the service delivers its results asynchronously (via callbacks) or synchronously.

If it delivers results synchronously, you must not call these methods on the UI thread. Despite the fact that the UI thread will simply wait for the results, while the Service and a binder thread do the actual work, your UI will still be blocked because the UI thread waits for the sake of the control flow.

So use AsyncTask, HandlerThread or Thread.

If the Service delivers its results asynchronously, you can most likely call the methods from the UI thread.